# Difference between 闇 (yami) and 怨 (on)

Tags: word-choice

In two anime series, HUNTER×HUNTER and D.Gray-man, the word 怨【おん】 was translated in the English subtitles as "darkness".

闇【やみ】 is another word for "darkness".  What is the difference between these two words?

Comment: Do you mean 闇 (yami) and 暗 (an)?

Comment: no, 闇 (yami) and 怨 (on)

Answer (score 1):

闇{やみ} and 怨{おん} are not really related at all.

- 闇{やみ} means "darkness", approximately (as well as some related concepts).
- 怨{おん} doesn't stand on its own, but is part of words like 怨{うら}み and 怨念{おんねん} which both mean "grudge", approximately.

Maybe if you explain what made you think they were related a better answer can be given?

Comment: In hunter x hunter and D.Gray-man (animes), the word "on" was translate(sub) as "darkness" so I thought it meant this .

---
sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mishear 暗{あん} as "on" like Dono suggested? Because 暗{あん} on the other hand is part of many words which are related to darkness... maybe just providing the full line of dialogue would be the easiest way to proceed?

Comment: i don't think i mishear, but it doesn't matter,the subtitles are probably wrong or a little changed than the original dialogue   
----
sorry for my bad english